# Remove widget added dynamically just before

Tags: jquery, grid-layout, dashboard, gridster

I'm doing a dashboard using Gridster. I have next code html:

```
<div class="gridster">
<ul id="widget_list">
  <li id="widg-1" data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2">1
    <a class='remove' href='#'>&times;</a>
  </li>
  <li id="widg-2" data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2">2
    <a class='remove' href='#'>&times;</a>
  </li>
  <li id="widg-3" data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2">3
    <a class='remove' href='#'>&times;</a>
  </li>
  <li id="widg-4" data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2">4
    <a class='remove' href='#'>&times;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>  
<button id="addWidget" data-role="button">Add widget</button>
```

And here, my code Javascript:

```
var gridster;
  $(function(){
    var log = document.getElementById('log');

    gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
      widget_base_dimensions: [100, 55],
      widget_margins: [5, 5],
      autogrow_cols: true,
      resize: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }).data('gridster');

    $(document).on( "click", "#addWidget", function(e) { 
       e.preventDefault(); 
       var li = $('#widget_list li').last();
       var data = li.attr("id");

       var array = data.split('-');
       var id = array[1];
       id++;
       gridster.add_widget.apply(gridster, ['<li id="widg-' + id + '">' + id + '<a class="remove" href="#">&times;</a></li>', 2, 2]);
    });

    $(".remove").click(function(){
        var id=$(this).parent().attr("id");
        alert(id);
        gridster.remove_widget($(".gridster ul").find("[id='" + id + "']"));
    });
  });
```

The problem is when I wanna remove a new widget which I added dynamically just before. When I wanna remove the widget which It's already added (the four ones), The function works perfectly. On the other case, it doesn`t work. The only thing strange I have seen, the program add "style="display: list-item;" as a param in the new created widget.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is of jQuery nature. All [dynamically created elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) are missing the declared binding for the remove action.

You should change the event handler to this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
    var id=$(this).parent().attr("id");
    alert(id);
    gridster.remove_widget($(".gridster ul").find("[id='" + id + "']"));
});
```

Comment: Oh my god... I'm so sorry for that terrible mistake... Thank you so much, i took 3 hours thinking on that...